# jQuery .on() method with multiple events - passing argument to event handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code :

```
$('.el')
    .drag("init", function () {
        //
    })
    .drag("start", function () {
        //
    })
    .drag("end", function () {
        //
    });
```

I couldnt find a way to pass the parameters in the case below

```
$('.el').on({

   drag: function(){
       //*init* functions  
   },

   drag: function(){
       //*start* functions  
   },

   drag: function(){
       //*end* functions  
   }

})
```

Is it possible to pass parameters while using `on` event delegation for multiple events at once. Or the only solution is using `on` for multiple times.

Comment: Are you talking about assigning event data?

Comment: `drag` is a method not an event, it can't be used with `on()`

Comment: Yes I am. But in the second scenario I couldnt find a way to pass the parameters..

Comment: You can't pass the parameters, `drag()` is a jquery plugin or something, you can't pass it to `on()` as an event and expect it to work ?

Comment: Are you using jqueryui?

Comment: Could you please check this [demo](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/live)

Comment: No it is a plug-in (linked above)

Comment: Where's the documentation for this plugin?

Comment: @Cerbrus http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag possibly

Comment: @Blazemonger: he's not using jQueryUI's draggable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading a library's api. Before asking a question on SO, please take a look at the library's docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably lead with the fact that you're using a plugin, more specifically [this plugin](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag).

The docs are pretty clear, there are events built in, such as `draginit`, `dragend` etc. that can be used instead of the `drag()` method

```
$(document).on({

   draginit: function(){
       //*init* functions  
   },

   dragstart: function(){
       //*start* functions  
   },

   dragend: function(){
       //*end* functions  
   }

}, '.el');
```